# Python Tkinter Text Widget not displaying contents from .txt file

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

I am currently creating a Python Tkinter program to edit and create .txt files. In doing so, I have created a file opening system using the File Dialog method and have the user selected path saved as: a file variable. I have looped through the file and added it to the text widget via the insert method. I opened a test .txt file with a 2 line content. It simply says: this is a test file. (New line) it is used for test purposes

**The problem is that the text widget appears blank**

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import FileDialog
master = Tk()

#all other code like filedialog opening code is here

editarea = Text(master,height=10,width=25)
editarea.grid(column=0,row=1)
f = open(file,"r")
for x in f:
    editarea.insert(END,x)
```

*This code is run in Python 3.7*

How do I make the Text widget display the contents of the .txt file **and can still be edited?**

Many Thanks
(For the future)

*I am aware the code above is a bit vage and won't run but you hopefully get the gist of my problem :)*

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined the value of `x` inside of your loop? The code you posted is correct, though it would be more efficient to read the whole file at once instead of line by line.

Comment: @BryanOakley As I am sure you can see from my code, I am a beginner to Python, though I have been doing it for a few years now. As you suggested above to read the whole of the file, what code would i use to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: You would use `editarea.insert("end", f.read())`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a better solution, whole file at once

```
with open(file, "r") as txtr:
    data = txtr.read()
editarea.insert(END, data)
```

this here is line by line

```
with open(file, "r") as txtr:
    data = txtr.readlines()
for x in data:
    editarea.insert(END, x)
```

if for some strange reason it didn't work, try this:

```
for x in range(len(data)):
    editarea.insert(END, data[x])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response to my question - the second method you posted worked perfectly.

Comment: happy to help, feel free to upvote/close the question hehe :)))